# Запуск nginx на домашнем пк

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi

тыкаюсь уже третий день. Дело в том что хочу запустить проект джанго на домашнем пк, просто для теста. Но именно через nginx не получается это делать, хотя напрямую через gunicorn/django всё нормально. Вот мои настройки:

---

пробросил порты на роутере:

```
внешний порт: 80
внутренний порт: 80
внутренний ip: 192.168.0.143
протоколы: все
```

как я понял роутер перенаправляет всё что долбится в 80 порт ip моего роутера на адрес: 192.168.0.143:80, то есть в nginx мне нужно вешать именно этот ip. по крайней мере с gunicorn/django это работает. То есть когда я запускаю gunicorn/django на 192.168.0.143 (на другом порте) то всё работает ок.

---

настройки nginx
файл: /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_django_test
создаю ссылку на: /etc/nginx/sites-endabled/my_django_test

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.0.143;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/fila/Pycharm_Projects/Other/gems;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

пробовал, так сказать, методом тыка, вставлять и мой ip роутера в server_name, так же не работало
ествественно после всех изменений рестартил

---

gunicorn запускаю стандартной командой:

```
sudo gunicorn gems.wsgi
```

он на локалке работает, всё нормально

---

в итоге стандартная надпись nginx
Welcome to nginx!
буду благодарен если подскажите что не так. подозреваю что что-то с портами не так или с настройкой nginx так как в принципе то он работает, но запрос переводить не хочет по какой-то причине.